# What's the name of the JavaScript engine used by iOS's UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, uiwebview

I know UIWebView uses WebKit as iOS's UIWebView's rendering engine.

What's the name of the JavaScript engine used by iOS's UIWebView? The one used by Chrome and is slower than mobile Safari's Nitro JavaScript engine.

Comment: [This is an excellent article](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/06/nitro-javascriptcore-and-jit.html) that discusses this. The engine didn't change (it is still JavaScriptCore) and Nitro is an extra level of JIT optimisation within that engine i.e. the engine didn't change (there is no "before" Nitro engine). A Google search for "[JavaScriptCore vs Nitro](https://www.google.com/#q=JavaScriptCore+vs+Nitro)" gives more articles saying much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just called [JavaScriptCore](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/ios-433/).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScriptCore is Nitro. When you use it through UIWebView, it's slower than in Safari because the JIT compilation is disabled.